# Delete all characters after a certain character from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a `textField` and I would like to remove all character after a certain character.

For instance if what I have in the textField is the word `Orange` and I want to remove all characters after the `n` I would like to get `Ora` after the deletion.

How can I delete all characters after a certain character from a string in Swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use  `StringProtocol` method `range(of string:)`, get the resulting range lowerBound, create a `PartialRangeUpTo` with it and subscript the original string:

**Swift 4 or later**

```
let word = "orange"
if let index = word.range(of: "n")?.lowerBound {
    let substring = word[..<index]                 // "ora"
    // or  let substring = word.prefix(upTo: index) // "ora"
    // (see picture below) Using the prefix(upTo:) method is equivalent to using a partial half-open range as the collection’s subscript. 
    // The subscript notation is preferred over prefix(upTo:).

    let string = String(substring)
    print(string)  // "ora"
}
```

[image]

Comment: In Swift 4 I like to use the `prefix(upTo:)`  and `suffix(from: )` methods instead. `if let index = word.range(of: "n")?.lowerBound
{
    let StringAfter = String(word.prefix(upTo: index))
}`

Comment: thank you very much! @fs_tigre your solution worked for me!! =D

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
guard let range = text.rangeOfString("Your String or Character here") else {
    return the text 
}

return text.substringToIndex(range.endIndex)
// depending on if you want to delete before a certain string, you would use range.startIndex
```