# Delete parameter from URL with swift

Tags: swift, string, url

I have an URL that looks like `myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url?id=4567` . 
I want to delete every thing after the `?` char. At the end the URL should look like `myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url`. how. can I achieve that? convert the url to a string? Regex?

Comment: Just look out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184984/delete-all-characters-after-a-certain-character-from-a-string-in-swift

Answer (score 15):

Use `URLComponents` to separate the different URL parts, manipulate them and then extract the new url:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url?id=4567")!
components.query = nil
print(components.url!)
```

> `myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url`

Answer (score 9):

A convenient extension on URL

```swift
private extension URL {
    var removingQueries: URL {
        if var components = URLComponents(string: absoluteString) {
            components.query = nil
            return components.url ?? self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> can I achieve that? convert the url to a string? Regex?

When working with URLs, it would be better to treat it as [`URLComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents):

> A structure that parses URLs into and constructs URLs from their
>   constituent parts.

therefore, referring to URLComponent what are you asking is to remove the the [query](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents/1780254-query) subcomponent from the url:

```
if var componenets = URLComponents(string: "myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url?id=4567") {
    componenets.query = nil

    print(componenets) // myapp://jhb/test/deeplink/url
}
```

Note that `query` is an *optional* string, which means it could be nil (as mentioned in the code snippet, which should leads to your desired output).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
let values = utl?.components(separatedBy: "?")[0]
```

It will break the string with `?` and return the array.
The first object of `values` give you your resultant string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each URL component separated from URl using

```
print("\(url.host!)") //Domain name
print("\(url.path)") // Path
print("\(url.query)") // query string
```