# How to cut last characters of string and save it as variable in swift?

Tags: swift, string

I have a string of `test@me`

now I want to create a code that let me cut where the `@` is and save it as a variable, so the expected result is `string1 = test` `string2 = @me`

a code will be something like this

```
func test(string: String) {
    var mString = string
    var cuttedString = mString.cutFrom("@")
    
    print(mString)
    print(cuttedString)
}

test(string: "test@me")
```

result:

```
test
@me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `extension` of `String` which performs the function you desire.  It takes a `String` and mutates the calling `String` by removing everything from that part on, and it returns the part that was removed.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    mutating func cut(from string: String) -> String {
        if let range = self.range(of: string) {
            let cutPart = String(self[range.lowerBound...])
            self.removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...)
            return cutPart
        }
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}

func test(string: String) {
    var mString = string
    let cutString = mString.cut(from: "@")
    
    print(mString)
    print(cutString)
}

test(string: "test@me")
```

> ```
> test
> @me
> ```

---

#### A *Generic* Implementation

Here is a generic implementation suggested by @LeoDabus in the comments:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult mutating func removeSubrange<S: StringProtocol>(from string: S) -> SubSequence {
        guard let range = range(of: string) else { return "" }
        defer { removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...) }
        return self[range.lowerBound...]
    }
}
```

It nicely demonstrates:

1. Extending a protocol instead of `String` to allow the function to be used with other types such as `String.Subsequence`.
2. The use of `@discardableResult` which allows the function to be called to shorten the `String` without using the substring that is returned.
3. Using a `guard let` statement to unwrap the optional return from `range(of:)` and provide an early exit if the range is `nil`.
4. The use of `defer` to delay the removal of the substring until after the substring has been returned which avoids the use a local variable.

Comment: Slightly shorter (and possibly a tiny bit more efficient): `self.removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...)`

Comment: @MartinR, any thoughts on `let cutPart = String(self[range.lowerBound...])` vs. `suffix(from:)`?

Comment: Good question. Given that `substring(from:)` has been deprecated in favor of slicing subscripts one might prefer the former.

Comment: No need to use a temporary variable for this. You can defer the removeSubrange

Comment: I would also make generic `extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {``mutating func cut<S: StringProtocol>(from string: S) -> SubSequence {` `guard let range = range(of: string) else {` `return ""` `}` `defer { removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...) }` `return self[range.lowerBound...]` `}` `}`

Comment: @vacawama https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185097/2303865 the same applies to suffix(from:). From the docs:  **Using the suffix(from:) method is equivalent to using a partial range from the index as the collection’s subscript. The subscript notation is preferred over suffix(from:).**

Comment: I would also suggest changing the method name and add discardable result `@discardableResult mutating func removeSubrange<S: StringProtocol>(after string: S) -> SubSequence {`

Answer (score 2):

Use `suffix(from:)` in combination with `firstIndex(of:)`

```
let string = "test@me"

let last = string.suffix(from: string.firstIndex(of: "@") ?? string.startIndex)
```

Note that this returns the full string if "@" is not found, you could instead return an empty string by replacing `string.startIndex` with `string.endIndex`

---

To split the string in two parts, ie "test" and "@me"

```
var first: String = ""
var last: String = ""
if let index = string.firstIndex(of: "@") {
    last = String(string.suffix(from: index))
    first = String(string.prefix(upTo: index))
}

print(first, last)
```

Comment: Good answer for getting the `@me` but can you include the code where you print the `test` string? to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String` subscript for this:

```
func test(string: String) {
    guard let atIndex = string.firstIndex(of: "@") else { return }
    
    let mString = string[string.startIndex...string.index(before: atIndex)]
    let cuttedString = string[atIndex..<string.endIndex]
    
    print(mString)
    print(cuttedString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func test(string: String) {
    let mString = string.prefix { $0 != "@" }
    let cuttedString = string.suffix(from: string.firstIndex(of: "@") ?? string.startIndex)
    
    print(mString)
    print(cuttedString)
}

test(string: "test@me")
// prints test
//        @me
```

But remember that `mString` and `cuttedString` are not `String` but `Substring`, so take care of correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this.

You could use `components(separatedBy:)` to break the string into pieces, and then add an `@` back to the last one:

```
extension String {
    func cutFrom(_ divider: Character) -> String {
        let array = components(separatedBy: String(divider))
        //For an Optional, `map()` returns nil if the optional is empty, 
        //Or the result of applying the closure to the unwrapped contents if not
        return array.last.map {String(divider) + $0} ?? ""
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could use firstIndex to find the index of the first divider character in the string, and then return a substring from that index to the end:

```
extension String {
    func cutFrom(_ divider: Character) -> String {
        //For an Optional, `map()` returns nil if the optional is empty, 
        //Or the result of applying the closure to the unwrapped contents if not
        return firstIndex(of: divider).map { String(self[$0..<endIndex])} ?? ""
    }
}
```

It might be cleaner to have both versions of the function return Optionals, and return NIL if the divider character can't be found. You also might want to adjust the logic to deal with strings where the divider character occurs more than once.